# Tabbed Fragment Activity creates unnecessary tabs for no reason?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Edit: [the project folder, ready for android studio](http://www.filedropper.com/effectivenavigation)

i download the EffectiveNavitaion.zip project from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) and started tinkering with it,

on 'DemoObjectFragment' i added a counter outside the function:

```
static int count =0
```

and i changed one line in OnCreateView()

```
((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
    (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "restored") + count++);
```

i noticed that when i swipe between alternating tabs for example (1,2,3,2,3,2,3), the tabs don't change (their count number remains the same) and we are seeing the old tab that was never destroyed

although onCreateView() on DemoObjectFragment keeps being called every swipe and it seems a new Fragment is being created every swipe and ends up not being used at all,

my question is: is there a reason for the behavior i am seeing or is there a problem in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i found this out, when a particular item is called, the 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter' will want to have the 2 direct neighbors ready for swiping,

it already has one (the one we come from), and it asks for the other one, the thing is, it only caches 3 at one time (the one we are viewing and its neighbors)

so it makes sence that alternating between 2 tabs always result in a getItem() call in 'FragmentStatePagerAdapter'